# php xml tag lowercase issue

Tags: php, xml

I have issue that I have a loop with xml tag for repeated elements. I store xml like below in php variable. you can there is "P" & "L" capital in xml tag but when echo that html variable it display lowercase tag and also when I put that html variable in existing xml request it make whole tag in lower case like : "packageline" but it should be as it is.

```
$html ='<con1:PackageLine></con1:PackageLine>';
```

i have tried lot of differnet technique but no success. can you suggest solution.

Comment: please post echo-code

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Please post the part of the code where you echo your variable, and what's echoed. Because, from what you've told us, there's no reason it shouldn't work : https://eval.in/765490

Comment: Lowercase tags are a trick (for case insensitivity) used by parsers if the load HTML. So somewhere in your toolchain you're loading the XML as HTML.